# Find_by and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested, where-clause

I got two models

**bcase.rb**

```
class Bcase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pimp
    has_many :c_entries, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :s_entries, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :c_entries, :s_entries

    validates_uniqueness_of :pimp_id
end
```

**c_entry.rb**

```
class CEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bcase
end
```

And I did following in my console:

```
irb(main):002:0> b = a.build_bcase
=> #<Bcase id: nil, pimp_id: nil, comment_text: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at
: nil, status: nil>

irb(main):003:0> (1..10).each {|i| b.c_entries.build(:order_no => i)}
=> 1..10

irb(main):004:0> b.c_entries
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: ni
l, order_no: 1, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated
_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 2, description: nil, hours
: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id:
nil, order_no: 3, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updat
ed_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 4, description: nil, hou
rs: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id
: nil, order_no: 5, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, upd
ated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 6, description: nil, h
ours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_
id: nil, order_no: 7, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, u
pdated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 8, description: nil,
 hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcas
e_id: nil, order_no: 9, description: nil, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>, #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 10, description: n
il, hours: nil, nrc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

So, I created an object of the bcase-type with the name "b" and then build 10 objects of the c_entry-type and the :order_no from 1 to 10. And `b.c_entries` shows me that it worked fine.

Now I was trying to get a single object out of this array with `find_by_order_no(1)` or `where(:order_no => 1)` and thats what I get.

```
irb(main):018:0> b.c_entries.where(:order_no => 1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

irb(main):025:0> b.c_entries.find_by_order_no(1)
=> nil
```

And that didnt give me what I wanted and I couldnt find out what I did wrong. I also tried to use `.first` but that didnt help.

```
irb(main):026:0> b.c_entries.find_by_order_no(1).first
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):26
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

irb(main):027:0> b.c_entries.where(:order_no => 1).first
=> nil

irb(main):028:0> b.c_entries.first
=> #<CEntry id: nil, bcase_id: nil, order_no: 1, description: nil, hours: nil, n
rc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):029:0> b.c_entries.first.order_no
=> 1
```

Anyone knows what to do?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not save any of them into the database. Build,  only creates stuff in memory. Either call `save` on build models or use `create`

Comment: So, there's no way to get a single object by order_no without saving it?

Comment: Not with ActiveRecord only. It allways queries the db . Actually it sometimes loads records from it's cache, but that happens only once you've loaded them from the db. And thatfor you have to save them first

Comment: You can use ActiveSupport `index_by(&:order_id)` to create an in memory hash and do lookups on that

Comment: Hmm ok, what I am trying to do is set up a form that creates 10 different objects with the order_no 1 to 10. And its not working the way I want to with field_for so I want to set up each form field myself but it has to be connected to the right object and I dont really know how to do that without saving them before.

Comment: You can always use [FormTagHelpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) to define custom forms without objects. Hoewever in most cases there is a soliution how to do it the rails way with objects. Feel free to post your exact problem as another question and i try to answer on it. Plz provide view code and describe explicitly the problem with fields_for and why it is not generating what you want. Plz also martk one of the answers as right, cause it solves your initial question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510781/nested-form-with-fixed-amount-of-created-objects-and-static-html-table Thats the new question then. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you are saying

```
b = a.build_bcase
```

it is just equivalent to

```
Bcase.new
```

Check this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/build.

What you should be doing is save the record by calling `b.save` or try `create`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class